# Finding probability from the mean, standard deviation, and number of trials of a normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Have been trying to answer this question for a few days now, and my assignment is due tomorrow.  I wouldn't typically ask for help, but some guidance would be appreciated.

A campground has found that the amount of hot water a camper uses while showering is
Normally distributed with a mean of $30$ liters and a standard deviation of $5$ liters.  You are in line behind 15 campers waiting to shower. If the campground has a $380$ liter hot water tank, what is the probability that there will be hot water when it is your turn to shower?

My assumption so far is that I have to use the central limit theorem in some manner, but I haven't been able to figure how.

Comment: You do not need the central limit theorem if you start with independent normally distributed random variables.  What you need to do  is to find the mean and variance of a suitably defined random variable related to there being enough hot water

Comment: Okay, so I need the mean value of the amount of water usage - assuming I use μ (of water usage) * n (number of trials) to get it.  I understand that part(I think).  I am unsure how I would find the variance.

Comment: Here's to get you started. Let $X_j\sim \mathcal{N}(30,5^2)$ denote the amount of water the $j^{\text{th}}$ camper in line uses. You need to evaluate $$P(X_1+\dots + X_{15}< 380)$$

Comment: Do you think you could give me more help?  I really am having trouble getting this.

Comment: Do you want any hot water at all to remain? Or are you a typical camper and want 30 liters remaining?

Answer (score 0):

Find the sum of 15 identical normal distributions with mean 30 L and variance = $sd^2$ = 25 L.  So, mean is 15x30 L = 450 L.  Variance = 15x25 L = 375 L.  Use cumulative distribution of N(450,375) to find P(X>380) = 1-P(X<380).

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, can you clarify why variance is used here? I was under the impression that I would need to use standard deviation as opposed to variance.

(I have a test coming up, I'd like to be able to study the specific theory behind this after I hand it in... Thank you so much btw)

Comment: No problem, and I used the normal distribution notation standard, which is represented by $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.  You can take the square root and plug in the standard deviation if that's what your cdf requires.  The reason variance was used in working out the problem is because variance is additive, while standard deviation is not, for probability distributions.